# C# - Base64 validator mistakes numbers with Base64 string

Tags: c#, .net, cryptography, console-application

I have a rather strange issue here, I have the following Base64 validator

```
        public static bool IsBase64String(this string base64)
        {
            Span<byte> buffer = new Span<byte>(new byte[base64.Length]);
            return Convert.TryFromBase64String(base64, buffer, out int bytesParsed);
        }
```

However strangely, it thinks the following string is base64! Not sure what is wrong.

```
5355220565819095
```

I'm using .Net 5.

**What I am trying to do**

I need to convert an array of bytes to Base64 , store it and then be able to tell if it is base64 then I can convert it back to bytes[]
Basically an efficient way of storing my bytes!

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/228920/discussion-on-question-by-feri-c-base64-validator-mistakes-numbers-with-base6).

Answer (score 0):

If this only applies to credit card numbers, you simply need to check the length (btw, I doubt it's a good idea to store credit card numbers).

MasterCard and Visa use 16 digits, while AmEx uses 15 digits, and from a quick search I get that some lesser known cards can vary between 13 and 19 digits.

A 13 digit card number results in a 20 char base64 string (including the "==" padding). So in the end all you need to check is the length of your string, if it's less than 20 chars, it's either an invalid or a plain card number, and anything of 20 chars or more should be decoded.

Edit: i forgot about the AES encrypted byte array, but that applies even more so.

Comment: That's a good idea, thanks, however I have other type of entries that need to be encrypted! Such as address or names. So basically all personal details are encrypted!

Comment: in that case you'd have to add contextual validation. above would help for creditcards, test if the length modulo 4 is zero, addresses typically contain spaces while base64 should not (as in: ignores them, i guess you don't split your json values over multiple lines). names may indeed be a problem when split into firstname and surname.